# Desktop angularjs website not opening on uc browser

Tags: javascript, browsers, angular.js

I have built a desktop site on angularjs.The problem i am facing is that i am not able to open it on uc browser on mobile.Is there any way to debug this issue ?

Comment: I've never even heard of UC Browser, but StatCounter says it is the third most popular browser with 8% market share!?  http://gs.statcounter.com/   My initial reaction was going to be "why do you care about some browser nobody uses."

Comment: Sorry but this question is considered off-topic because it is about programming and debugging. Most likely more suitable on Stack Overflow however there is several questions already that exist on SO, e.g [(1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38241205/how-can-i-inspect-element-in-a-uc-browser-in-android-phone-on-my-machine), [(2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35921070/debugging-uc-mini-browser), and many more [(3)](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Buc-browser%5D+is%3Aquestion). Please visit the SO Help Centre before reposting if you think the question is unique.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller thats why i am worried